# MailKit IMAP search mail by the subject field

Tags: c#, wpf, email, imap, mailkit

I have a wpf software which needs to get inquiry emails that contain specific codes in the subject. basically search and get a mail by the contents of subject field. I cannot find any relative information, perhaps it would be possible to receive all the mails and then do the search, but that is highly inefficient. I would appreciate if someone could at least tell me if it is even possible to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible to be done. Have a look at the MimeKit [documentation](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_Search_SearchQuery.htm)

Answer (score 1):

We have multiple options to search.

Please find the sample code

```
var query = SearchQuery.SubjectContains ("Search Text1").Or (SearchQuery.SubjectContains ("Search Text2"));
var uids = client.Inbox.Search (query);
```

Reference: MailKit.Search.SearchQuery

Examples : [Link](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/Documentation/Examples/ImapExamples.cs)

Please find the methods.
[Method List](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_Search_SearchQuery.htm)